# How can I ensure a PHP class is found when compiling Haxe?

Tags: php, haxe, ufront

I am compiling a UFront application which worked prior to Haxe 3.4. After upgrading it started generating this error when using remoting:

`PHP Fatal error:  Class 'haxe__Unserializer_DefaultResolver' not found…site/ufront/www/lib/haxe/Unserializer.class.php on line 554`

As a temporary fix I inserted this statement at the top of that file:

`require '_Unserializer/DefaultResolver.class.php';`

Obviously that will disappear the next time I compile. How can I ensure that PHP finds the DefaultResolver class?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by putting these lines in my Server class:

```
#if php
untyped __php__("require 'haxe/_Unserializer/DefaultResolver.class.php'; ");
#end
```